# Deploy asp.net mvc core app to azure app service from Linux

Tags: azure

I have a Linux développement computer.

I have created a new asp.net core mvc project with this command:

```
dotnet new mvc
```

I have build and publish this application with dotnet publish.

Now, what I want to do is to transfer the binaries on my azure app service.

I can do it by hand but I want to automate a lot of things. My question is : is there a way to type a command that will transfer files to my azure app service ?

Please note azure portail gives me an xml file which contains login, pass and url (for Windows msdeploy.exe ?)

I have tried to pass arguments to dotnet build command (I have read some tutorials but it does not seem to work on Linux)

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is relevant: [Create an ASP.NET Core app in App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-dotnetcore)

Comment: Yes i have read it but I need a git repository with this solution

Comment: Would highly recommend getting a GIT repository. Anyways, there's also [Deploy your app to Azure App Service with a ZIP or WAR file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip), or [some docker stuff here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image)

Comment: I have tried your first link with git. Is there a way to avoid to type password each time i run git push azure master ? Thanks

Comment: You can create an SSH-key: [How do I disable password prompts when doing git push/pull?](https://superuser.com/questions/338511/how-do-i-disable-password-prompts-when-doing-git-push-pull).

Comment: I know how ssh key works, but in the case of azure app services, i have no way to declare my private key on the repository